# Dynamic parameters using variable as key

Tags: ruby

Lets say I have a method foo:

```
def foo(options = {})
  ...
end
```

I want to pass a variable as the key.

```
fooKey = "option1"
foo(fooKey: "bar1", option2: 'bar2')
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the hashrocket syntax

```
foo(fooKey => 'bar1', :option2 => 'bar2')
```